# Total sum of errors from multiple servers using powershell, get-eventlog and Measure-Object

Tags: powershell, sum, aggregate, event-log

I am trying to get the total number of errors on multiple servers using

get-eventlog -logname application -cn $server | ?{$*.eventid -eq "10" -or $*.eventid -eq "20"} | | Measure-Object

The ouput looks something like this

```
Count          : 41
Average        : 
Sum            : 
Maximum        : 
Minimum        : 
Property       : 
PSComputerName : server1 

Count          : 44
Average        : 
Sum            : 
Maximum        : 
Minimum        : 
Property       : 
PSComputerName : server2

Count          : 47
Average        : 
Sum            : 
Maximum        : 
Minimum        : 
Property       : 
PSComputerName : server 3
```

I couldn't figure out how to further sum up the count from all the servers.
Eg. total errors: 132

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(foreach ($server in $servers){
  get-eventlog -logname application -cn $server |
  ?{$_.eventid -eq "10" -or $_.eventid -eq "20"} }) |
  Measure-Object
```

Comment: Thanks mjolinor. Simplistic and brilliant!